# Reduce MongoDB Balancer induced failures, in a sharded cluster

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding, distributed-system

The version of MongoDB used is 4.2. We have the MongoDB balancer disabled during normal hours. However, we have recently wanted to use MongoDB in a sharded Multi DC setup. This sometimes requires us to update the zones or zone key ranges of certain shards. The mapping between zone and shard is one is to one i.e S1 -> Z1,  S2 -> Z2, S3 -> Z1

In such a case, if one of the mapping is updated to S1 -> Z1,  S2 -> Z2, S3 -> [], all the data from S3 is expected to drain to S1 and S2. This happens, and takes a lot of time (5 hours for 30G of data). We also see a lot write failures during the activity. Is there a way to go about this, without disabling the balancer.

Comment: What are the failures then?

Comment: @D.SM the failure message says: Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13388 (StaleConfig): 'Transaction <transaction-> was aborted on statement 3 due to: an error from cluster data placement change :: caused by :: Encountered error from <shard1>:27101 during a transaction :: caused by :: version mismatch detected for <collection1'> on server 10.*.*.*:27300.

Comment: You may consider adding this, the command that failed, and other relevant information to your question.

Comment: @D.SM, it was not a single command. We are on production with this system. Hence this was when we updated the zone key ranges in MongoDB